# How to compile conditional 3 color-scale Excel rule

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, color-scheme

I want to know what I would need to type into the formula box in excel to solve the problem outline below:

Key: `*Variable/Cell*`

```
IF *cellnumber* = 0 shade cells red
IF *cellnumber* > (more than) 0 but < (less than) *cell number* shade cells yellow
IF *cellnumber = *cellnumber* shade cells green.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want Conditional Formatting.  Pre-Excel 2007 go to the Data menu and click conditional formatting.  Excel 2007 or later go to the Home ribbon and click Conditional Formatting.  [Here](http://www.contextures.com/xlcondFormat01.html) is a guide to conditional formatting that shows something similar to what you need.

As for the second and third condition that apply to the value in another cell, you can put a reference in the conditional formatting window similar to "Cell Value : Equal to :" then =$A$1 in the value box.

For 2011:
Any quotes below should NOT be typed.  This assumes the cell you want to check against is A1.

1. Select the range you want to be colored
2. Home Ribbon -> Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules
3. New Rule
4. "Format Only Cells That Contain"
5. Choose: Cell Value & between
6. Enter in "0" and "=$A$1" (remember, no quotes)
7. Click Format -> Fill, choose yellow
8. Click Ok
9. New Rule
10. "Format Only Cells That Contain"
11. Choose Cell Value & Equal
12. Enter in "0"
13. Click Format -> Fill, choose red
14. Click Ok
15. New Rule
16. "Format Only Cells That Contain"
17. Choose Cell Value & Equal
18. Enter in "=$A$1"
19. Click Format -> Fill, choose green
20. Click Ok

Comment: Thanks for this, have looked but is still fairly difficult for me as I would still have to enter custom formulas in the conditional formatting box, which I dont know how to do.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Follow the steps above in order.  The most recently entered conditional formatting is applied first.

Comment: +1 for the nice step by step. And Ryan, I think you mean 2010 :p